# Ranking by date using DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a table that looks like this:

[image]

I have developed the following formula to solve this solution:

```
RANK____ = 
RANKX (
    FILTER ( 'tableName', 'tableName'[Disease] = EARLIER('tableName'[Disease'])),
    'tableName'[Released Date],
    ,
    ASC,
    DENSE
)
```

The issue I am having is that is showing the following error message: "EARLIER/EARLIEST refers to an earlier row context which doesn't exist."

There is no previous filter context in my analysis. What am I missing? Keep in mind that the final user would have to select any drug they are interested in and see for which disease that drug was first released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the RANKX function here. You can use the RANK function.
Something like this:

```
RANK____ = RANK(DENSE,,ORDERBY([Released Date],ASC),,PARTITIONBY('tableName'[Disease]))
```

Your desired output suggests that you want to partition by drug and not disease. If you indeed want to partition by drug, just change the PARTITIONBY() clause to PARTITIONBY('tableName'[Drug]).

The error message: "EARLIER/EARLIEST refers to an earlier row context which doesn't exist.", speeks for itself. For the EARLIER function to work, there needs to be an earlier row context and there isn't one.